# Текстовый редактор WinApi

Tags: winapi, windows, c++, ооп

Мне нужно сделать текстовый редактор на WinApi C++. Текстовый редактор работает с планарным текстом(т.е. не какого форматирование не предусмотрено). Соответственно я хочу сделать один большой многостаночный TextBox на всё окно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, что бы TextBox менял свои размеры в соответствии с изменениями размеров окна в котором он находится?

Answer (score 3):

```
case WM_SIZE:                                                       
    hInstance1 = GetWindowWord(hChild, GWW_HINSTANCE);
    Edit1 = CreateWindow(
        "EDIT",
        "",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_BORDER
            | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_READONLY, 
        0, 0, 1000, 500,
        hChild,
        100,
        hInstance1,
        NULL
    );
    nWidth = LOWORD(lParam);
    nHeight = HIWORD(lParam);
    MoveWindow(Edit1, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, 1);
    ShowWindow(Edit1, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    break;
```

Может, это поможет тебе. Я не проверял. Но когда-то делал такое.

Comment: CreateWindow на каждый WM_SIZE? явная ошибка, нужно вынести CreateWindow туда где создаётся основное окно или в обработку WM_CREATE.